# Using Xib's for a multi-device UI

Tags: objective-c, xib

I am using a xib file to create the view for a settings view controller.  The user taps an object in the main view which animates a narrow view (preferably 35% the width of the screen) over from the left.

How do I set a relative width using xibs.  Right now I am setting the simulated metrics - > size property to freeform and I only have the option to hard code a width in points.

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout - make a width constraint for the view:

```
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[myView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:.35]];
```